# what is the performance of an OFDM system in one-path channel (Flat response channel),with no multi path propagation?

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, telecommunications, optical, ofdm

i work on modelling a OFDM system in a indoor optical wireless channel (LOS channel), since my channel is LOS there is no multi -path propagation , so the delay spread of my channel is much smaller than the length or duration of one IFFT output sample, Cyclic Prefix length is the duration of multiple of IFFT output symbols , now i cant determine the suitable number of samples needed to be inserted to the CP ?
CP is critically needed as it turns the linear convolution to circular convolution causing a much easier equalization technique in the frequency domain , how to determine the length of cyclic prefix in this case , thanks so much in advance

Comment: Isn’t there an AGC delay time for regulating CP?

Comment: no, my channel dimensions is small that all reflection paths components  arrive to the receiver within one IFFT output sample duration , thus the effect of multi path propagation of light is not observed at all .

Comment: So you use a fixed gain receiver

Comment: yes .. the receiver has an optical analog front end that receives the signals and removes the DC offset set by the transmitter, then it is converted to digital signal to be digitally processed .

Comment: I don’t know the optimum for your IFFT discriminator but generally correcting the initial f estimation error depends on the f offset correction in any system. Once captured and corrected then SNR of demodulation is maximum. How you utilize IFFT depends on your latency which determines CP symbol length . In real hardware it can be as low as 1 symbol if CNR is high or much more if CNR is low.

Answer (score 0):

In the limit of no multipath, your CP only needs to deal with the 'end effects' (bandwidth) of your channel.

In practice, having a CP longer than that eases the synchronisation accuracy that you need when selecting the portion to transform.

Answer (score 0):

The CP acts as a buffer between the symbol and the wideband noise from the discontinuity at the symbol boundary.

The higher-frequency components of that noise need to be filtered out as they exceed your target bandwidth, so you run the output IQ data through a lowpass filter, which introduces a relation between output samples.

If that filter were a perfect \$0\ \textrm{dB}\$ for the allocated bandwidth and \$-\infty\ \textrm{dB}\$ everywhere else, with a length equal to the symbol length, no cyclic prefix would be needed, but even digital filters are not perfect. So, the prefix length reduces the inter-symbol crosstalk introduced by this filter. The opposite extreme would be a cyclic prefix equal to the length of your filter, which would reduce the inter-symbol crosstalk to zero, but obviously reduces symbol rate too much.

So I'd choose the cyclic prefix length based on the number of taps with an absolute value above a certain threshold; any inter-symbol crosstalk caused by smaller taps is then just regular noise.

Any particular reason why you want to use OFDM on a flat channel with just a single sender and receiver?

Comment: i  am working on a simple Li-Fi demonstrator , i have seen a research paper in which OFDM was used over a flat channel to provide a high date rate

Comment: @MoaazSherif, OFDM gives you a limit on sample rate based on processing power. If you look at the 802.11ad standard, they just use QAM on a \$2\ \textrm{GHz}\$ wide channel because calculating the FFT on a stream with \$2\ \textrm{GS/s}\$ would require quite a lot of computation power.